# Problem - Firefox suddenly can't establish a connection to the server at localhost

Tags: firefox, xampp

I am new to Ubuntu, and I have the problem that up until yesterday everything was working fine, but today firefox cannot access to my localhost. I have checked the firewall, and it is inactive. I have tried changing the chmrod access but nothing seems to work. Does anyone know how I can get this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It indicates that the server at `localhost` isn't working. Open a terminal window and type `service apache2 status`.

Comment: Thanks man! I don't know why, but Apache was turned off! It's solved now :)